# merge rows csv by id ruby

Tags: ruby, hashmap, inject, fastercsv

I have a .csv file that, for simplicity, is two fields: ID and comments. The rows of id's are duplicated where each comment field had met max char from whatever table it was generated from and another row was necessary. I now need to merge associative comments together thus creating one row for each unique ID, using Ruby.

To illustrate, I'm trying in Ruby, to make this:

ID | COMMENT
1  | fragment 1
1  | fragment 2
2  | fragment 1
3  | fragment 1
3  | fragment 2
3  | fragment 3

into this:

ID | COMMENT
1  | fragment 1 fragment 2
2  | fragment 1
3  | fragment 1 fragment 2 fragment 3

I've come close to finding a way to do this using inject({}) and hashmap, but still working on getting all data merged correctly. Meanwhile seems my code is getting too complicated with multiple hashes and arrays just to do a merge on selective rows.

What's the best/simplest way to achieve this type of row merge? Could it be done with just arrays?

Would appreciate advice on how one would normally do this in Ruby.

Answer (score 4):

Keep the headers and use group by ID:

```
rows = CSV.read 'comment.csv', :headers => true
rows.group_by{|row| row['ID']}.values.each do |group|
  puts [group.first['ID'], group.map{|r| r['COMMENT']} * ' '] * ' | '
end
```

You can use 0 and 1 but I think it's clearer to use the header field names.

Comment: This one works perfectly, simple and elegant. found that I didn't need the pipe delimiter as was in my example, so would retain each row as an array... thanks

Answer (score 1):

With the following csv file, tmp.csv

```
1,fragment 11
1,fragment 21
2,fragment 21
2,fragment 22
3,fragment 31
3,fragment 32
3,fragment 33
```

Try this (demonstrated using irb)

```
irb> require 'csv'
  => true
irb> h = Hash.new
 => {} 
irb> CSV.foreach("tmp.csv") {|r| h[r[0]] = h.key?(r[0]) ? h[r[0]] + r[1] : r[1]}
 => nil 
irb> h
 => {"1"=>"fragment 11fragment 21", "2"=>"fragment 21fragment 22", "3"=>"fragment 31fragment 32fragment 33"}
```

Comment: can't convert nil into String is what I got back - but probably a quick fix I could write a check for, though 1st suggestion works for my needs